# Pass structure to dll (freepie) in ctypes

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, struct, ctypes

Freepie has a dll file that you can use to pass data into the program. Here is my script to do so:

```
import time
import ctypes
from ctypes import byref, c_int, POINTER


class freepie_io_6dof_data(ctypes.Structure):
    __fields__ = [
        ("Yaw", ctypes.c_float()),
        ("Pitch", ctypes.c_float()),
        ("Roll", ctypes.c_float()),
        ("X", ctypes.c_float()),
        ("Y", ctypes.c_float()),
        ("Z", ctypes.c_float())]

q = ctypes.CDLL("E:\\Program Files (x86)\\FreePIE\\freepie_io.dll")  # Load DLL
slots = q.freepie_io_6dof_slots()
data = freepie_io_6dof_data()
data.Y = ctypes.c_float(0)
q.freepie_io_6dof_write.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, POINTER(freepie_io_6dof_data)]
while True:
    q.freepie_io_6dof_write(0, 1, byref(data))
    print(data)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

However, when freepie gets the data, it shows it as a different number each time I run the program and usually something like 6.34523234E-36. The expected output would be 0, where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're going wrong in (not) understanding floating point numbers, exponential notation, and imprecise measurements. Your number is 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000634523234.

Comment: Even if I change the number, the float will always read a random number. Printing the float in python shows that it is 0.0. Rounding in freepie shows the number as zero even if I change the value it is fed.

Comment: It's likely there's some math behind the scenes that should return 0, but just doesn't round instead.

Comment: However, if that were true then when I feed it 4, the value would change. But it doesn't. I believe it could have something to do with the fact I'm using a pointer, as the value changes with each program restart. So my guess is that it has something to do with the actual pointer itself?

Comment: It's `_fields_` (**ONE *underscore***), **not** `__fields__`.

Comment: @ChrisFati After changing that, I now have this error: `TypeError: second item in _fields_ tuple (index 0) must be a C type`. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Thank you, ChristiFati! Other than taking the brackets off the datatypes, your answer was flawless. Thank you!

Comment: You misspelled my user name so I wasn't notified by your comment. Anyway glad to hear you sorted it out. And yes, the 2nd tuple element should be a type not an instance of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos in the main code led to the erroneous performance. After changing `__fields__` to `_fields_` and removing the brackets from `ctypes.c_float` the code works fine!

Here is the final code:

```
import time
import ctypes
from ctypes import byref, c_int, POINTER


class freepie_io_6dof_data(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("Yaw", ctypes.c_float),
        ("Pitch", ctypes.c_float),
        ("Roll", ctypes.c_float),
        ("X", ctypes.c_float),
        ("Y", ctypes.c_float),
        ("Z", ctypes.c_float)]

q = ctypes.CDLL("E:\\Program Files (x86)\\FreePIE\\freepie_io.dll")  # Load DLL
slots = q.freepie_io_6dof_slots()
data = freepie_io_6dof_data()
data.Y = ctypes.c_float(0)
q.freepie_io_6dof_write.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, POINTER(freepie_io_6dof_data)]
while True:
    q.freepie_io_6dof_write(0, 1, byref(data))
    print(data)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```